# SharePoint UserGroup Web Service - Retrieve users (nested sub-groups)

Tags: sharepoint

We have a need to retreive all users if we know the group name in a SharePoint. We are planning to use the following MOSS out of the web service to retrieve the users from a group. If the group has nested sub groups, do you know how this web service behaves?

Also, does the user accessing the web service has to be a super user having permission to all SharePoint sites? Is this web service based on a site or a document library?

/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx?op=GetUserCollectionFromGroup

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In MOSS you cannot have SharePoint group inside another SharePoint group. You can only have AD groups or users inside a SharePoint group.

You only need to have Full Read permissions to the web application to retrieve this information. You can set this permission by using the stsadm utility.

stsadm.exe -o addpermissionpolicy -url http://myFQUrl -userlogin "domain\user" -permissionlevel "Full Read"

Answer (score 0):

These tutorials may help:
http://blogs.sharepointace.com/post/Another-way-to-retrieve-SharePoint-List-Data-Use-built-in-functionality!.aspx

http://vspug.com/tonstegeman/2007/10/03/export-user-information-to-excel-using-quot-export-to-spreadsheet-quot-in-sharepoint-2007/

Comment: Broken links.  I know this is an old question/post, but that's why it's better is to post the actual answer, not just links to it.  Many moderators would remove these kinds of answers because of that.